# Progress - Get full response from web service

Tags: web-services, soap, response, progress-4gl, openedge

I have problem with geting full response from SOAP WS in Progress OpenEdge. 
"bprowsdldoc" app generated full call and output structure to DATASET, but in DATASET I have only last element of "document" type.
Response looks like this:

```
<GetDocumentsResponse>
     <documentsCount>3</documentsCount>
     <document>
        <content filename="file1.xml" mime="application/xml"> [base64] </content>
     </document>
     <document>
        <content filename="file2.xml" mime="application/xml"> [base64] </content>
     </document>
     <document>
        <content filename="file3.xml" mime="application/xml"> [base64] </content>
     </document>
     <documentsInfo>All done.</documentsInfo>
</GetDocumentsResponse>
```

My goal is to get all "document" elements in output DATASET (count of 3 is only a sample) or get full response XML as LONGCHAR.
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Web service is internal in my company and calling it requiers VPN connection, so I can't give You link.
But bprowsdldoc generated a code like this for method "GetDocuments":

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dateStart AS DATE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dateEnd AS DATE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE documentsCount AS INT64 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE document NO-UNDO
    FIELD docId AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE content NO-UNDO
    FIELD filename AS CHARACTER 
        XML-NODE-TYPE "ATTRIBUTE" 
    FIELD mime AS CHARACTER 
        XML-NODE-TYPE "ATTRIBUTE" 
    FIELD content_Text AS RAW 
        XML-NODE-TYPE "TEXT" 
    FIELD document_id AS RECID 
        XML-NODE-TYPE "HIDDEN" .  

DEFINE DATASET documentDset 
    XML-NODE-TYPE "HIDDEN" 
    FOR document, content
    PARENT-ID-RELATION RELATION1 FOR document, content
        PARENT-ID-FIELD document_id.

DEFINE VARIABLE documentsInfo AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

RUN GetDocuments IN hDocumentHandlingPort(INPUT dateStart, INPUT dateEnd, OUTPUT documentsCount, OUTPUT DATASET documentDset, OUTPUT documentsInfo).
```

After calling this method I get proper response for variables *documentsCount* and *documentsInfo* but in TEMP-TABLE *content* I got only one row with  *document* element from response (there should be 3 for dates from 2017-03-16 to 2017-03-16 as ine example response on the top of my post).

Response in WSDL looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="GetDocumentsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="documentsCount" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="document" type="ns1:documentType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="documentsInfo" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I think that problem may be related to *maxOccurs* attribute of element *document* - it's unbounded and maybe there should be some numeric value...

Can You help mi handle this problem?

Comment: Perhaps if you showed your code we might be able to identify the error?

Comment: @Tom thank You for interesting in my problem. Glad to see so big authority in Progress technologies here. :) I hope my additional informations will be helpfull for You to indentity my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to defect PSC00323593, described in knowledge base, this situation is a bug. But there is always light in the dark, so there is also workaround for it:

> Use the WSDL Analyzer (bprowsdldoc) with -show100style parameter to
>   generate documentation. Using the older syntax works as desired,
>   returning all expected records.
>
> In the scenario encountered, the alternate documentation uses type
>   LONGCHAR for parameters. It was then possible to combine code from
>   original documentation (specifically the TEMP-TABLE and DATASET
>   definitions) with the code from the -show100style documentation. The
>   READ-XML method was used to read the LONGCHAR output parameter into
>   the DATASET.
>
> or
>
> Add APPEND option to the DATASET parameter.

You can find full article [here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056249).